# Adding Headers to NGINX Ingress using ConfigMap not working

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to pass my client IP address through my NGINX Ingress using Kubernetes on Azure

I've created this configmap for the NGINX config to add the headers:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  X-Real-IP: $remote_addr;
  X-Forwarded-For: $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  X-Forwarded-Proto: $proxy_x_forwarded_proto;
  use-forwarded-headers: "true"
  use-proxy-protocol: "true"
  real-ip-header: "proxy_protocol"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: custom-headers
  namespace: default
```

Then added this config to reference the previous file:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  proxy-set-headers: "custom-headers"
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
```

If I describe my nginx controller:

```
kubectl describe deploy ingress-nginx-controller
```

I can see the line:

```
--configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
```

If I describe the ingress-nginx-controller configmap

```
kubectl describe configmap ingress-nginx-controller
```

I can see the following in the data section:

```
proxy-set-headers:
----
custom-headers
```

If I log out the nginx.conf file in my controller though, I can't see the changed values. For example this is still the default:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $remote_addr;
```

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use? It is important information to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I'm currently using 1.20.9

Comment: Verified the same issue with v1.21.2

Comment: yes, I thought it was possible to omit the namespace for default but no.
I also had an issue with proxy-headers-hash-bucket-size being too low which prevented deployment once the new headers were added

proxy-headers-hash-bucket-size: "256" 

in the configmap fixed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the namespace prefix for proxy-set-headers value. Because you have deployed `custom-headers` configmap to the default namespace, it should be

```
data:
  proxy-set-headers: default/custom-headers
```

Comment: thanks, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I have run some tests and the answer provided by the user [Yadhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6782727/yadhu) should be correct.

**Problem explanation:**
You are using `proxy-set-headers` configuration option for [ConfigMaps](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#configmaps). It is well described [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#proxy-set-headers):

> Sets custom headers from named configmap before sending traffic to backends. The value format is namespace/name. See [example](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/docs/examples/customization/custom-headers)

In this example you can find configuration of the nginx ingress controller via a ConfigMap to pass a custom list of headers to the upstream server.

Look at the example yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  proxy-set-headers: "ingress-nginx/custom-headers"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
```

**Problem soultion:**
You need to use proper format in this option:

```yaml
proxy-set-headers: "<your namespace>/custom-headers"
```

Comment: thanks, much appreciated