Issue with `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-headers` annotation on Kubernetes nginx ingress
I'm trying to add headers to the responses on a specific ingress being managed by the kubernetes nginx ingress controller.  Thus far I have done the following:
Set global-allowed-response-headers: "Content-Security-Policy" in ingress-nginx-controller ConfigMap in the ingress-nginx namespace.
Created a ConfigMap with the Headers:
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: qc-ingress-headers
  namespace: qc
data:
  Content-Security-Policy: ...

Added the following annotation to the ingress:
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ....
  namespace: qc
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-headers: qc-ingress-headers
  ...

I've also tried nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-headers: qc/qc-ingress-headers based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/69583275.
However, I'm not seeing the header when I visit the ingress, and I don't see any references to more_set_headers in the nginx.conf in my ingress-nginx-controller pod.
At this point I'm at a loss.  I'd appreciate help, or someone pointing out things I can do to test this.
